# dot net Memory Disposal, Is CLR garbage collector deals with other resources?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, clr

DOT NET garbage collector can only deals with memory resources or it also handles other resources used by orphaned object?

How CLR deals to free these other resources used by orphaned object.

Comment: This **must** be a duplicate, but I can thing the question it is a duplicate off...

Comment: might be duplicate, I tried here first but not get. Now I got some answer and keywords to learn about CLR memory management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .Net GC manages only objects that are put up on managed heap, i.e. managed objects. These managed objects may inturn access unmanaged objects like DB connection or a file handle etc. The developer needs to free these resources by implementing IDisposable or Finalize, depending on your needs.

MSDN states that:

> A type must implement Finalize when it
>   uses unmanaged resources such as file
>   handles or database connections that
>   must be released when the managed
>   object that uses them is reclaimed.
>   See the IDisposable interface for a
>   complementary and more controllable
>   means of disposing resources.

Here's the link for the same: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx

Comment: No, using Finalize is not the correct way of releasing unmanaged objects. You should use the IDisposable interface for that.

Comment: If you want to use deterministic disposal - use IDisposable interface. You never know when your finalizer will be called

Comment: Agreed. My mistake. The best practice suggests that IDisposable should be used whenever possible.

Answer (score 4):

The GC only deals with managed objects.

All unmanaged resources need to be dealt with manually:

1. Implement the [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface on any types that use unmanaged resources.
2. Ensure that you call the [`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) method when you're done with using any objects that implement `IDisposable`. This is often done by using a [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) block.